# Would broadcasting packets be the best solution to "Server to Many Clients" type VoIP situation?

Tags: network-programming, udp, broadcast, multicast

I'm trying to set up a network infrastructure and program a one to many VoIP system.

It will work in a private WiFi network.

We'll have one server streaming audio packets and many clients requesting/receiving those exact same packets (UDP).

I don't want to send the packets point to point, as I want this to scale to as many clients as possible without hitting a bandwidth limit.

There won't be any other machines on the network other than the server and the clients.

Should I be broadcasting the packets from the server? Would they be sent only once and grabbed by many clients without significant bandwidth overhead that way?

Or should I use multicasting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast packets go to every client on the subnet attached to your server. They won't travel beyond that subnet.

Multicast packets allow clients on **any** subnet to subscribe to the multicast,provided intervening routers or layer-3 switches are configured to support multicast.

Will there be any routers or layer-3 switches in this network?

If so, you'll need multicast. If not, you can use broadcast.

From a bandwidth perspective, each packet is sent only once and picked up by every client - there should be little or no difference in the load on the server. The load elsewhere will depend on the network configuration and the number of clients in any remote subnets.

Comment: Thank you, I know networking just enough to survive and this is quite new to me. I want to keep this as simple as possible: One wireless router, and possibly hundreds of clients in an enclosed space. If I can change the subnet mask with the router, I should be able to have more than 255 clients am I right? Am I right in thinking that in a VoIP situation, if I want retransmission of dropped packets, broadcasting wouldn't work well? I could use multicast then but retransmission requests from many clients might lead to congestion? Trying to figure out the bottlenecks.Thanks again.

Comment: If you're using UDP there's no guaranteed delivery, and no way to track dropped packets, so this won't be a problem. In any case, with VOIP if a packet's lost it's already too late to ask for it again, as the data stream will have moved on. You can change the subnet mask as you wish - every bit shorter will roughly double the size of the subnet. If you're talking hundreds of clients then a /16 mask will do (65534 clients)

Comment: Don't forget other infrastructure: you might need a DHCP server. I'd recommend using a Wireless Access Point rather than a router (no subnetting to worry about), and be prepared to use more than one - WiFi is nowhere near as reliable in practice as the specifications would suggest.